# Should Cassandra store derived value?

Tags: cassandra

I am building up a RESTful service to return 3 variables: isMachine, hasWheel, isCar.

```
{
    "isMachine": true,
    "hasWheel": true,
    "isCar": true 
}
```

"isCar" is a derived data, isCar = isMachine && hasWheel.

I am using Cassandra as datastore.

The data ingestion happen every week.

I have 2 options:
1. Do the calculation during data-ingestion phase, and retrieve it without calculation.
2. Calculate the value "isCar" on the fly when reading.

My questions: What is the best practice? I understand there are always trade-off for the decision. I would like to know the reason.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 3 variables are examples not really what you are storing, it is a simple question of where you need better performance: retrieval or insertion/indexing. If you are doing data ingestion once a week you are probably not bottlenecking here so I would move as much calculation as possible here

Answer (score 1):

The answer does not concern Cassandra but the domain of your application -- if ever in future you'd need to know why a vehicle is not a car you have no way due to a loss of information.

As far as performances are concerned the computation is ridiculously simple and retrieving two Boolean columns instead of one from Cassandra has no impact on performances.

If the computation required hard work and data would be read often I would calculate once and save them (if loss of information is an acceptable situation)

Comment: The reason why concern Cassandra because it sometime being used as a cache server, and as such it stores calculated value and denormalized value.

Comment: You mentioned that "loss" of information. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I just mean that if of a computation you save only the output you lose the information that generated the output. E.g.if one day you will be asked to extract all vehicles that are not cars due to missing wheels you won't be able. However my rule is the one in last paragraph: it depends on how heavy is computation and how often the db will be queried for that result